# <Provider> does not support changing `store` on the fly

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I recently began learning how to use React-Native and Redux together. I got an error in the IOS simulator that I can't figure out how to fix, and I was wondering if anyone had seen this before.

Here's the error:

> Provider does not support changing store on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions.

I followed that link mentioned in the error message, but it seemed like it needed me to be using Webpack. In the link, where it references `if(module.hot)`, I got the following error when trying to use this solution:

> Unable to resolve module

So I'm not sure where to go from here. My project so far is very small. I have my `index.ios.js`, then an app folder containing a components folder, a store folder and a reducer folder. The structure looks like this:

- index.ios.js
- app

  - store

    - index.js
  - component

    - index.js
  - reducer

    - index.js

Here is my code:

`index.ios.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
  AppRegistry,  
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import {configureStore} from './app/store';
import Main from './app/components/Main';

export default class introToRedux extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={configureStore()}>
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('introToRedux', () => introToRedux);
```

`components/Main.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

var Main = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
});

var mapStateToText = (state) => {
    return {
        text: state.text
    }
}

module.exports = connect(mapStateToText)(Main);
```

`reducer/index.js`

```
module.exports = (state={}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

`store/index.js`

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducer from '../reducer';

var defaultState = {
    text: "default text"
}

export var configureStore = (initialState=defaultState) => {
    return createStore(reducer, initialState);
}
```

Any help on this would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you export `configureStore()`? You might as well

```
const initialState = {
    text: "default text"
}

export default function reducer (state=initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

`createStore()` should be executed once.

index.js

```
// import stuff

const store = createStore(reducer)

class IntroToRedux extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(IntroToRedux, document.getElementById('root'))
```